# numpy image pixel values changing when appending to ndarray of images

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I have a ndarray containing images  of size 32x32x3. So if there's 70,000 images, the shape of this array is (70000, 32, 32, 3)

I'd like to add 5000 more images of of shape 32x32x3 to this array, but I'm having trouble doing this.

```
#images.shape: (70000, 32, 32, 3)
#new_img.shape: (32, 32, 3)
images = np.append(images,np.array([new_img]), axis=0)
```

This appears to work at first, as the new shape of images is (70001, 32, 32, 3), but something goes wrong when accessing this last image. It seems that the individual pixel values in all three channels increase across the board, resulting in mostly white images. Why would this be? And what does it take to correctly append additional images to this array?

Comment: Since you don't show how `new_img` is created or used, it's hard to say why it might be turning out white. We need a reproducible example.

Comment: check the dtypes

Comment: Yep, that's right. I didn't even realize the base dataset had values divided by 255. appending the image converts the dtype from uint8 to float32. So when I try to show the image, the values appear right to me, but the image comes out white because all the pixel values need to be divided first